# django retrieve specific data from a dictionary database field

Tags: django

I have a table that contains values saved as a dictionary.

FIELD_NAME: extra_data

VALUE:

```
{"code": null, "user_id": "103713616419757182414", "access_token": "ya29.IwBloLKFALsddhsAAADlliOoDeE-PD_--yz1i_BZvujw8ixGPh4zH-teMNgkIA", "expires": 3599}
```

I need to retrieve the user_id value from the field "extra_data" only not the dictionnary like below.

```
event_list = Event.objects.filter(season_id=season_id, event_status_id=2).value('extra_data')
```

Comment: You could parse extra_data as a string and then use split() function to get the user_id.

Comment: Why, why, why are you storing a dictionary in a text field in Django? It offers so many cool and rational ways to manage all sorts of data.

Comment: I wondered the same thing.  It is from an Django Package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing a dictionary as text in the code you can easily convert it to a python dictionary using [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) - although I don't know why you'd want to as it opens you to all sorts of potential malicious code injections.

```
event_list = eval(Event.objects.filter(season_id=season_id, event_status_id=2).value('extra_data'))
user_id = event_list['user_id']
print user_id
```

Would give:

```
"103713616419757182414"
```

**Edit:**
On deeper inspection , thats not a Python dictionary, you could import a JSON library to import this, or declare what `null` is like so:

```
null = None
event_list = eval(Event.objects.filter(season_id=season_id, event_status_id=2).value('extra_data'))
user_id = event_list['user_id']
```

Either way, the idea of storing any structured data in a django textfield is fraught with danger that will come back to bite you. **The best solution is to rethink your data structures.**

Answer (score -1):

This method worked for me. However, this works with a json compliant string

```
import json
json_obj = json.loads(event_list)
dict1 = dict(json_obj)
print dict1['user_id']
```